# Group operations among the open sets of a topological space.

Tags: category-theory

Let X be a topological space and $\Omega \left(X \right)$ be the set of all open sets of X. Does anyone have a concrete example of X, where we can define a familiar algebraic structure on $\Omega\left(X\right)$, for example of a Group. Also,  what is the categorical term for such things? (In contrast with group object in Top)

Comment: $\Omega(X)$ is always a complete distributive lattice, with $\bigvee\mathscr{U}=\bigcup\mathscr{U}$ and $\bigwedge\mathscr{U}=\operatorname{int}\bigcap\mathscr{U}$ for $\mathscr{U}\subseteq\Omega(X)$.

Comment: May I ask why you need this?

Comment: I am aware of that. I should have exclude that, since as you mentioned, the lattice is always there. For example, think of a finite Topology, whit the action of a dihedral group on its open sets. But, this is not a concrete example, since I am not suggesting any actual representation of open sets, as elements of a dihedral group.

Comment: It is possible to define a group structure on any set. It is just a matter of taste how well group structure and topology should fit together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well.. it's not a usual approach of anything..

As Brian wrote in the first comment, $\Omega(X)$ becomes a *complete distributive lattice* naturally.
Moreover, if $X$ is a top.group, then $\Omega(X)$ will also carry a *semigroup* structure.

Comment: Yes. Thanks. I may delete this question then.

Comment: Well, no, no.. You stirred me up some other thoughts, but could not yet substantiate them.. Maybe you want to learn some about *locales*: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_Heyting_algebra